# JqPlot Event for MouseOver

Tags: events, graph, mouseover, jqplot

I am using JqPlot with Javascript and would like some help for a GraphMouseOver event. I see that there is the following:

```
jqplotDataMouseOver
```

I would like the same as the above, yet instead of MouseOver for just the data, I am looking for a MouseOver for the whole graph.

Is there a list of Events for JqPlot that I can have a look at, or can someone help me with the name of this event?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `jqplotMouseMove`. E.g.,

```
$('#chart1').bind('jqplotMouseMove', 
    function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
        alert('here');
    }
);
```

Going through the `jquery.jqplot.js` file, the following events are raised:

```
'jqplotClick'
'jqplotDblClick'
'jqplotMouseDown'
'jqplotMouseUp'
'jqplotRightClick'
'jqplotMouseUp'
'jqplotMouseMove'
'jqplotMouseEnter'
'jqplotMouseLeave'
```